# The type name or alias xxxx could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I have the following interface defined in a RepositoryPattern project:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Domain;

namespace RepositoryPattern
{
    public interface IRepository
    {
        List<Car> GetCars();
    }
}
```

The unity section of my XML configuartion looks like this:

```
  <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <namespace name="RepositoryPattern" />
    <container>
      <register type="IRepository" mapTo="SqlServerRepository" />
    </container>
  </unity>
```

When I run the application, I get the following error:

`The type name or alias IRepository could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name.`

Answer (score 2):

I got it.  I needed to add the assembly section:

```
  <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <assembly name ="RepositoryPattern"/>
    <namespace name="RepositoryPattern" />
    <container>
      <register type="IRepository" mapTo="SqlServerRepository" />
    </container>
  </unity>
```